# SSO Okta is sitting at the okta developer page after login . NOT returning to the ACS URL of the service provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, service-provider, idp

Two scenarios

**scenario #1**. Logged in to Okta developer portal independently + Logged out from Service provider(SP)

**scenario #2**. Logged out from Okta + Logged out from Service Provider

In **scenario #1**, I tried to login into the SP, It get logged in via Okta(already logged in) and redirected back to the SP page with the logged-in state. Working as expected.

In **scenario #2**, I tried to login into the SP => it get redirected to Okta developer login page => logged in through GitHub => Redirected to the Okta developer portal dashboard page with logged-in state and sitting on the same okta developer page.NOT redirecting back to the SP page.

[Scenario #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpJfk.png)

[Scenario #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arx5X.png)